# Extremely slow query, no blocking, not bad execution plan: Why?

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, slowdown

I have a table valued function that insists of 8 INSERT INTO statements. For each INSERT INTO statement, they follow the same structure as:

```
DECLARE @TABLE1 TABLE (Column1, 2, .....);

INSERT INTO @TABLE1 (column1, 2, ...)
    SELECT * FROM BASETABLE1
```

The function returns a table that joins those 8 tables (using LEFT HASH JOIN). In the past, this function would run about 7 minutes to complete (the base table(s) are big that of over 1 million data), but most recently, this function is very slow and took forever.

Here are what I've done to get an idea of the slowness:

1. I've checked the blockings, no blocks of the server;
2. I've checked the execution plan, no major changes recently, and the base tables are properly indexed with updated statistics;
3. I looked at the `sp_who2`, I have to admit this server is pretty busy, a lot of agent jobs and tableau connections are going on at the same time, and quite some processes involve with this function. However, I would say the level of business is the same as before and now, and why the slowness is just happened recently?
4. I also checked the active expensive queries, and obviously the most expensive ones are those INSERT INTO queries;
5. We patched the windows (that hosting this SQL Server) about 10 days ago, so I wondered if that patch has any impacts on this slowness? We also rebooted the SQL Server 4 days ago trying to fix the issue. The situation was better after the reboot (but not as good as the issue happened before), and today, it became worse again.

Anything else that I might missed?

Comment: Depending on how many records are being inserted into the @Tables and how they are being utilized later in the query, you may find a performance boost by converting them to #Tables with appropriate indexes applied. Table Variables are just big ole heaps.

Comment: @RossBush I also think of moving table variables to temp tables as well. But I am confused that why it was good before but bad now?

Comment: It is hard to formulate an answer to this question as an array of factors could be adversely affecting performance. Some things to consider: Has IT changed the network, has indexes been removed, are indexes being maintained, are statistics being utilized, has the data suddenly shifted to a partition with slower IO, how does temp db's memory look when taxed. If you are not getting deadlocks then it is likely some  part of your system has gone into overdrive. You also mentioned a update to your server's os, I would not see that as impediment, can you positively point to that as a game changer?

Comment: You need to show us your execution plan for assistance with performance (see Paste The Plan).

Comment: "But I am confused that why it was good before but bad now" - SQL Server will re-evaluate what it considers the best way to carry out its task based on statistics. These obviously change over time, so once a tipping point is reached a perfectly good query can become unusable. This is a good lesson in understanding that SQL is a declarative language, i.e. all you are doing is describing to the database engine the results you want. You are not (generally) telling it how it should go about obtaining those results. It works that out itself, and it can change over time.

Comment: Cardinality estimates for table variables changes with SQL Server version, as does what you can do in terms of indexing. Which version on SQL Server are you using? Also, by specifying a `hash` hint, you are limiting the optimizer. For example, you are forcing the join order to match the query text (which may or may not be optimal). You also have no statistics for table variables. I suggest removing the hash hint (let SQL choose to use one if it wants to), adding indexes (if supported), and/or switching to temp tables (which means no more TVF). Also, why can't you just query the base tables?

Answer (score 1):

Your

```
insert into ( columns1, 2, etc... )
   select * from BaseTable
```

Is that your actual query?  The *, I would expect you to explicitly indicate the columns you wanted to pull.  I have seen weird things if a table structure was altered, are you getting what you really think are the correct columns and same sequence as insert is expecting?  Also, you have no WHERE clause, so you are pulling the entire database from one into a memory table and for what benefit / purpose?

You mention a `table valued function`.   Is that what this overly broad insert statement is, or is there some other context to it and you are just masking it for us?